# System call mktime ignores tm_isdst flag

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix, mktime

another one question regarding mktime and DST

Linux, Ubuntu, time zone is set to Europe/Berlin i.e. current time is CEST:

```
>date
Mon Aug 22 16:08:10 CEST 2016
>date --utc
Mon Aug 22 14:08:14 UTC 2016
```

everything okay so far.

Now I try to run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{

    struct tm   tm = {0};
    int secs;

    tm.tm_sec = 0;
    tm.tm_min = 0;
    tm.tm_hour = 12;
    tm.tm_mon = 9 - 1;
    tm.tm_mday = 30;
    tm.tm_year = 2016 - 1900;

    tm.tm_isdst = 0;
    secs = mktime(&tm);
    printf("%i\n", secs);

    tm.tm_isdst = 1;
    secs = mktime(&tm);
    printf("%i\n", secs);

    tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    secs = mktime(&tm);
    printf("%i\n", secs);

    return 0;
}
```

and get

```
1475233200
1475233200
1475233200
```

which is in all three cases wrong (1 hour offset):

```
>date -d @1475233200
Fri Sep 30 13:00:00 CEST 2016
```

So I am a bit puzzled now, is my timezone somehow broken? Why is tm_isdst flag ignored completely?

**Edit: @Nominal Animal had the answer: mktime modifies tm_hour! I wonder where it is documented?!**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void reset(struct tm* tm){
    (*tm) = (const struct tm){0};

    tm->tm_sec = 0;
    tm->tm_min = 0;
    tm->tm_hour = 12;
    tm->tm_mon = 9 - 1;
    tm->tm_mday = 30;
    tm->tm_year = 2016 - 1900;
}

int main()
{

    struct tm   tm;
    int secs;

    reset(&tm);
    tm.tm_isdst = 0;
    secs = mktime(&tm);
    printf("%i\n", secs);

    reset(&tm);
    tm.tm_isdst = 1;
    secs = mktime(&tm);
    printf("%i\n", secs);

    reset(&tm);    
    tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    secs = mktime(&tm);
    printf("%i\n", secs);

    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
1475233200
1475229600
1475229600
```

Comment: 1) The behavior seems odd.  To _better_ trouble shoot, reset **all** fields again (or at least print them) after calling `mktime(&tm);` as `mktime()` may adjust the `tm` fields.  2) Use a matching  format specifier like `printf("%i\n", (int) secs);` or `printf("%lld\n", (long long) secs);` to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: It might *seem* odd, but it really is not odd. Indeed, [`mktime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html) modifies its argument -- in particular, the `tm.tm_hour` and `tm.tm_isdst` fields in this case.

Comment: @Nominal Animal  What is `odd` is that `mktime()` is not expected to change `tm` as `tm` is in the primary range in the first 2 cases.  _ahh_ maybe not in the first case.  Hmmm - a dst of 0 in summer time may change to 1.

Comment: @chux could you please post an answer so i can accept, it seems to work.. really odd this stuff

Comment: @NominalAnimal could you please show where it is documented that tm_hour is modified! this seems to be the point

Comment: @Stasik: `mktime()` **always** changes `tm_isdst` to `0` or `1`. The behaviour is described (as I explained in my answer) at the [man 3 mktime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html) man page, as well as in much more abbreviated form [in POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can now see how one would find this confusing. Think of `mktime()` as having signature

```
time_t mktime_actual(struct tm *dst, const struct tm *src);
```

where the `time_t` result is calculated based on (normalized) `*src`, and the normalized fields and whether daylight savings time applies at that time, is saved to `*dst`.

It is just that the C language developers historically chose to use only one pointer, combining both `src` and `dst`. The above logic still stands, though.

See the [`man mktime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html) man page, especially this part:

> The mktime() function converts a broken-down time structure,
> expressed as local time, to calendar time representation.  The
> function ignores the values supplied by the caller in the tm_wday and
> tm_yday fields.  The value specified in the tm_isdst field informs
> mktime() whether or not daylight saving time (DST) is in effect for
> the time supplied in the tm structure: a positive value means DST is
> in effect; zero means that DST is not in effect; and a negative value
> means that mktime() should (use timezone information and system
> databases to) attempt to determine whether DST is in effect at the
> specified time.

> The mktime() function modifies the fields of the tm structure as
> follows: tm_wday and tm_yday are set to values determined from the
> contents of the other fields; if structure members are outside their
> valid interval, they will be normalized (so that, for example, 40
> October is changed into 9 November); tm_isdst is set (regardless of
> its initial value) to a positive value or to 0, respectively, to
> indicate whether DST is or is not in effect at the specified time.
> Calling mktime() also sets the external variable tzname with
> information about the current timezone.
>
> If the specified broken-down time cannot be represented as calendar
> time (seconds since the Epoch), mktime() returns (time_t) -1 and does
> not alter the members of the broken-down time structure.

In other words, if you change your test program a bit, say into

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static const char *dst(const int flag)
{
    if (flag > 0)
        return "(>0: is DST)";
    else
    if (flag < 0)
        return "(<0: Unknown if DST)";
    else
        return "(=0: not DST)";
}

static struct tm newtm(const int year, const int month, const int day,
                       const int hour, const int min, const int sec,
                       const int isdst)
{
    struct tm t = { .tm_year  = year - 1900,
                    .tm_mon   = month - 1,
                    .tm_mday  = day,
                    .tm_hour  = hour,
                    .tm_min   = min,
                    .tm_sec   = sec,
                    .tm_isdst = isdst };
    return t;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct tm   tm = {0};
    time_t secs;

    tm = newtm(2016,9,30, 12,0,0, -1);
    secs = mktime(&tm);
    printf("-1: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d %s %lld\n",
           tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_mday,
           tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec, dst(tm.tm_isdst), (long long)secs);

    tm = newtm(2016,9,30, 12,0,0, 0);
    secs = mktime(&tm);
    printf(" 0: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d %s %lld\n",
           tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_mday,
           tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec, dst(tm.tm_isdst), (long long)secs);

    tm = newtm(2016,9,30, 12,0,0, 1);
    secs = mktime(&tm);
    printf("+1: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d %s %lld\n",
           tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_mday,
           tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec, dst(tm.tm_isdst), (long long)secs);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

then running it produces output

```
-1: 2016-09-30 12:00:00 (>0: is DST) 1475226000
 0: 2016-09-30 13:00:00 (>0: is DST) 1475229600
+1: 2016-09-30 12:00:00 (>0: is DST) 1475226000
```

In other words, it behaves exactly as described (in the quote above). This behaviour is documented in C89, C99, and POSIX.1 (I think C11 also, but haven't checked).

Answer (score 1):

> On successful completion, the values of the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components of the structure are set appropriately, and the **other components** are set to represent the specified calendar
>   time, ...  C11dr §7.27.2.3 2

When calling `mktime(&tm)`, the original values of `tm` are not range restricted.

Because of the the first  `mktime(&tm)` call, certainly `tm.tm_isdst` and `tm.tm_hour` were adjusted to 1 and 11. So OP's following code `tm.tm_isdst = 1;` and `tm.tm_isdst = -1;` did not affect the timestamp.

Better to set all fields to investigate.

```
struct tm   tm0 = {0};
struct tm   tm;
int secs;

tm0.tm_sec = 0;
tm0.tm_min = 0;
tm0.tm_hour = 12;
tm0.tm_mon = 9 - 1;
tm0.tm_mday = 30;
tm0.tm_year = 2016 - 1900;

tm = tm0;
tm.tm_isdst = 0;
secs = mktime(&tm);
printf("%i\n", (int) secs);

tm = tm0;
tm.tm_isdst = 1;
secs = mktime(&tm);
printf("%i\n", (int) secs);

tm = tm0;
tm.tm_isdst = -1;
secs = mktime(&tm);
printf("%i\n", (int) secs);
```